# How to let my discord bot respond to a message without a prefix

Tags: discord, discord.net

I'm pretty new to C# and am coding a discord bot for my own server. I'm trying to get my bot to respond to a message sent by someone (E.G someone says "dye" and my bot would respond with "no u" without prefix needed.

I've been searching all over the internet and know I need something along the lines of a "messagereceived event" but it keeps saying that it doesn't exist or I'm not using the directive or an assembly reference. 
I'm not sure how to fix it or what I'm doing wrong since I'm quite new, and I can't find a solution. Hope someone can help

Comment: You should show us what you got so far and/or what errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 2):

So I think what you are asking is having the bot detect when a certain phrase is said and then respond.

Assuming you are subscribed to the MessageReceived event (the event that runs everytime a new message is sent anywhere your bot is on) You get the given SocketMessage and get its content property. If that property matches "no u" then just have it reply in that channel. To do that get the context via something like this:

Subscribe to the MessageRecieved event:
_discord.messageRecieved += MessageReceivedEvent; //where _discord is your DiscordClient and MessageReceivedEvent is your task to run on that event

```
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
    {
        if(message.Content.equals("dye")
        {
             message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("no u");
        }
        //command implementation here
    }
```